# Handling async in module.exports

Tags: node.js

I want load some js modules asynchronously, each js module has some db operation. How can I ensure that each require to module.export is loading asynchronously.

```
module.export = require('module-a');
module.export = require('module-b');
module.export = require('module-c')
```

I would want to execute module-c after module-b, and module-b after module-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try below code

```
var module_c = require('module-c');

module_c.somemethod()
.then(function() {
  var module_b = require('module-b');
  module_b.method1().then(function(){
    var module_a = require('module-a');
    ...
    ...
  });
});
```

JS modules can be load asynchronously, by calling them in respective callback functions or promises

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async/await**.

Note: This is not properly tested, but if it doesn't work straight away, it should at least give you an overview on how to do it.

```
const loadModule = async() => {
  const result = await module_c.someOperation();
  return result;
};
```